# Cómo compruebo si un valor pertenece a un array en Bash

Tags: array, bash

Estoy escribiendo un script para ver si alguien se loguea en un servidor. Uso [Check_MK](https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk.html) como alternativa a Nagios y es la primera vez que uso arrays en Bash.

Este es el script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRS="/etc/init.d/"

listablanca=(
        it-cba-02.ip-tel
        vm-jrodeiro.ip-tel
    )

hostname=`w -s -h -u | awk '{print $3}'` > /dev/null
status=0
statustxt=OK

if [ -z "$hostname" ] ; then
    echo "0 Login logstatus=0;0;2 No hay usuarios conectados"
else
    for i in "${hostname[@]}"; do

        if [ "$i" != "${listablanca}[*]" ] ; then
            status=2
            statustxt=CRITICAL
            criticalhost+="$i"
        fi
    done
fi

echo "$status Login logstatus=$status;0;2 $statustxt $criticalhost"
```

Cuando me logeo desde 2 pc (una en el array listablanca y la otra no), este es el resultado del script:

```
2 Login logstatus=2;0;2 CRITICAL it-cba-02.ip-tel
10.1.9.43
```

El estado critico parecería estar OK, pero "it-cba-02.ip-tel" no tendría que aparecer ya que pertenece al array `$listablanca`. Solo debería aparecer "10.1.9.43" y en teoría tendría que devolver solo una linea de salida.

¿Alguien puede darme una mano? No encuentro el error pero me imagino que está en el array.

Comment: Ayudaría que pusieras algún "echo" aquí y allá para que veamos de dónde van saliendo estos datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dada una lista fija de valores, quieres ver si otra lista pertence a la primera.

Esto se puede hacer de varias maneras, pero a mí me gust la expresada en [How do I test if an item is in a bash array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177589/40596), consistente en convertir cada elemento de la lista en un índice. De este modo saber si un elemento pertenece consiste en mirar si ese índice existe:

```
#!/bin/bash

lista=("hola" "como estás" "yo bien")
a_comprobar=("como estás" "blabla" "hola")

declare -A indices
for key in "${!lista[@]}"
do 
  indices[${lista[$key]}]="$key"
done

for nombre in "${a_comprobar[@]}"
do
   if [[ -n "${indices[$nombre]}" ]]; then
      echo "-$nombre- SÍ está en el array"
   else
      echo "-$nombre- NO está en el array"
   fi
done
```

La ejecución de este script devuelve:

```
-como estás- SÍ está en el array
-blabla- NO está en el array
-hola- SÍ está en el array
```

---

En tu caso concreto, el script se reduciría a algo así como:

```
DIRS="/etc/init.d/"

listablanca=(
        "it-cba-02.ip-tel"
        "vm-jrodeiro.ip-tel"
    )

declare -A indices
for key in "${!listablanca[@]}"
do 
  indices[${listablanca[$key]}]="$key"
done

servidores=$(w -s -h -u | awk '{print $3}') > /dev/null  # mejor una variable con nombre no común; también, mejor $()
status=0
statustxt=OK

if [ -z "$servidores" ] ; then
    echo "0 Login logstatus=0;0;2 No hay usuarios conectados"
else
    declare -a criticalhost
    for nombre in "${servidores[@]}"; do
        if [[ -z ${indices[$nombre]} ]]; then  # -z contrario a -n
            status=2
            statustxt=CRITICAL
            criticalhost+=("$nombre")
        fi
    done
fi
```

Donde `-z` valida si la longitud es cero.

Fíjate además del uso de `criticalhost+=("$i")`. Esta es la manera de añadir elementos a un array, para que después puedes imprimir su contenido con algo así como:

```
if [ $status -eq 2 ];
    for host in "${criticalhost[@}}"; do
        echo "$host -- crítico"
    done
```

Comment: Creo que no se entendió bien, lo que quiero hacer, es que el script verifique  si hay alguien conectado, si es asi y este dentro de la lista blanca, que el resultado sea OK, si no hay nadie, obviamente tambien tiene que dar OK, y si hay alguien fuera de la listablanca, que en ese caso de CRITICAL. El ultimo echo que uso, es la salida necesaria para el plugin del Check MK, en mi caso $criticalhost tendria que darme en la misma linea, los hosts que esten conectados (fuera de la listablanca). Muchas gracias!

Comment: @JuanPabloRodeiro y eso hace este script. ¿Lo has leído y probado? Nótese que mi respuesta es un esbozo de cómo afrontar la tarea, la solución final debe depender de ti, pues tampoco das demasiados datos en la pregunta.

Comment: @JuanPabloRodeiro tienes razón. Mi primera edición tenía una errata porque yo mismo no había probado el script :P Lo corregí, el tema es que estamos haciendo un bucle sobre `for nombre in "${servidores[@]}"; do`, y no sobre `$i` como tenía inicialmente.

Comment: esa parte la habia corregido, funciona perfecto, lo unico que me falta es saber como hago para que la variable criticalhost sea solamente las PC que no esten dentro de listablanca. Se entiende?

Comment: @JuanPabloRodeiro para eso yo uso `criticalhost+=("$nombre")` y así `$criticalhost` es un array que contiene precisamente esos valores. ¿Se llena en tu caso? Debería. Dado que necesitas una cadena, puedes decir `echo "$status ... ${criticalhost[*]}"` para que expanda todos los valores del array.

Comment: si, se llena, pero sigue mostrandome it-cba-02.ip-tel (estaria dentro de la listablanca), y me devuelve 2 lineas de salida, seguramente si me logueo desde otra PC mas, me saldrian 3 lineas, no se como hacer que la variable se llene con los nombres separados por un espacio, o cualquier caracter, no con un salto de linea.

Comment: @JuanPabloRodeiro ya sé, seguramente el problema está en cómo definimos el array. Debería ser con comillas en cada uno de los elementos. Mira mi edición.

Comment: lo había probado así, pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: @JuanPabloRodeiro deberás hacer un poco de debugging. Mira qué valen exactamente las variables. Por ejemplo, di `cat -vet - <<< "$servidores"` para detectar si hay saltos de línea ocultos por allí. Sin datos de un [mcve] no puedo ayudarte más.

Comment: fue suficiente ayuda, ahora me pongo a ver donde puede estar eso. Te agradezco la ayuda, abrazo!

Comment: @JuanPabloRodeiro ¡mucha suerte! No dejes de volver para comentarnos qué solucionó tu problema. No dejes de usar `echo` aquí y allá para visualizar mejor qué tienes en cada caso.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que esta función te ayude:

```
function arrayContains() {
    local needle="$1"
    printf "%s\n" ${listablanca[@]} | grep -q "^$needle$"
}
```

La puedes usar así:

```
arrayContains $i
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
    status=2
    statustxt=CRITICAL
    criticalhost+="$i"
fi
```

Yo la uso para varios scripts, de manera que compruebo si un valor existe en un array de datos.

En caso de existir, ejecuto lo que sea necesario.